# 3rd part API call in Meteor with Iron Router and Angular

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I need to get data from a 3rd party API into an Angular template (I'm using angular-meteor) and would like to use Iron Router (so I can use Fast Render). The idea is to setup a route accessible from both server and client:

```
Router.route('/foo/:bar', { 
    name: 'foo', 
    data: function() { 
        Meteor.call('fetchFoo', this.params.bar, function(error, data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            return data; 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

The problem is even though the data printed to the console, it's not returned to the 'foo' template. From there it would need to be passed to the Angular template.

Any ideas?